# Best way to select SUM and a unique value from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which calculates a sum of values for a certain column and also needs to retrieve a single value, both from the same table.

I was wondering, since the whole table will be read to calculate the sum, is there a way I can select the wanted value at the same moment ?

Is this possible or do I need to make 2 distinct `SELECT`s on the table as shown below?

The current code from my query is :

```
SELECT [columns],

(SELECT SUM(value) FROM votes WHERE postid=p.postid) AS charge,
(SELECT value FROM votes WHERE postid=p.postid AND userid=u.userid) AS currentVote

FROM posts p, users u WHERE p.userid=u.userid
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case it is possible as you want the SUM of the value for votes related to the posts for a specific user.

Instead of using nested queries you could use something like this:

**Based on the Comments I have updated the query:**

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a0920/9

```
SELECT p.postid, sum(v.value) AS charge,
v.value AS currentVote
FROM posts p,
     users u,
     votes v
WHERE p.userid=u.userid
  AND v.postid = p.postid
group by p.postid;
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. Didn't think of just using all 3 tables in the FROM clause. :)

Comment: As written, this is going to return one row.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @sgeddes Yeh.. it's late. Making a fiddle and rechecking this because the group by will cause additional issues grrr.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I don't think it will return only one row. The issue is the group by...

Comment: @meewoK . . . The `sum()` without a `group by` should cause the compiler to interpret the query as an aggregation query.  That is, one row.  The values of the other variables should be arbitrarily chosen from the rows.  Perhaps `distinct` with an aggregation function performs differently from a normal query; I'm not aware that it does and the documentation doesn't suggest it.

Comment: @meewoK . . . I think the reaction in the comments is less to your query -- which is reasonable (except for the join syntax) -- and more to the acceptance of an answer that seemed obviously incorrect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I accepted the answer that he provided not because the query he gave was correct, but because it gave me an idea on how to obtain the solution by myself. But thanks everyone for your inputs !